# FeathersJS REST Multiple Query String

Tags: rest, feathersjs

With the FeathersJs REST client - how can I query a single field with multiple values?

Eg. if I have a Books service and I want to retrieve all books written in the year 1990, 1991 and 1992. I'd assume I'd call:

`/books?year[]=1990&year[]=1991&year[]=1992`

Although this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for the common [database adapter querying syntax](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html). The correct way to query for what you are looking for is:

```
year: {
  $in: [ 1990, 1991, 1992 ]
}
```

The corresponding query would be

```
/books?year[$in]=1990&year[$in]=1991&year[$in]=1992
```

Parsing this query string requires using the extend query parser [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) which you can enable with

```
app.set('query parser', 'extended');
```

Since the query is a string, if you need the actual number values for the year you might also have to convert it the query in a `before` hook (although most database usually allow both).